# Solving integral $\int \int _{\Bbb{R}^2} e^{-(3x+2y)^2 - (4x+y)^2} dx dy$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How to solve this integral $$\iint _{\Bbb{R}^2} e^{-(3x+2y)^2 - (4x+y)^2} dx dy$$

I expanded the power terms to get $$I = \iint _{\Bbb{R}^2} e^{-5(5x^2 + y^2 + 4xy)} dx dy = \int e^{-5y^2} \int e^{-25x^2 -20xy} dx dy$$

perhaps this is related to some tricks like of solving $\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2} e^{-x^2} dx$ like of multiplying two integrals and then applying Jacobian?

Comment: There's an obvious change of variables to try. Let $u =3x+2y$ and...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious change of variables is

$$ u = 3x + 2y, v = 4x+y $$

Then

$$ dudv = \left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|dxdy = \left|\begin{matrix} 3 & 2 \\ 4 & 1 \end{matrix}\right|dxdy = 5 dxdy $$

And

$$ I = \frac15 \iint_{\Bbb R^2} e^{-(u^2+v^2)}\ dudv $$

Switch to polar coordinates ([see solution here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates)) and you're done.

Comment: Nice, perhaps we will be taking absolute value of Jacobian value?